# How can I use ActiveProfiles with Spring Boot tests with WebMvcTest?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller, spring-test-mvc

I have a unit test that is testing a RestController using `@WebMvcTest`. The the controller class autowires a service class that I would like to mock. I found that I can use `@Profile` and `@Configuration` to create a config class for specifying primary beans to use when a profile is active. I tried adding an active profile to my unit test class, but it says it failed to load the ApplicationContext. I'm not sure how I can do that while using `@WebMvcTest`.

```
@ActiveProfiles("mockServices")
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(VoteController.class)
public class VoteControllerTest {
...
```

It seems I may be approaching this wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Edit:

Here is my configuration class:

```
@Profile("mockService")
@Configuration
public class NotificationServiceTestConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public VotingService getVotingService() {
        return Mockito.mock(VotingService.class);
    }
}
```

The error I'm actually getting is:

org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'VotingService'

I was able to solve it by using `@MockBean` for VotingService in my Unit Test class. However, I want to use the Profile configuration I have in NotificationServiceTestConfiguration without having to call out mock beans.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What is the stack trace? How does your Configuration class for mockServices look like?

Comment: @arseniyandru I edited my post to provide more detail. Let me know if you need anything else. Thanks

Comment: Try using Mockito @Mock annotations instead of using a separate config for mocks

Comment: You have a typo: "mockServices" vs. "mockService". Make sure you spell the profile name exactly the same in `@Profile` and in `@ActiveProfiles`.